# Jquery index() doesn't find my element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Today I've a small problem with jQuery .index() function.
I've a list of div possessing the **primaryContract** class. Of of these div contains too the **selected** class.
I want to receive the index of this selected element.
I try a lot of manipulations but nothing works, the function returns only -1 (it's the fail return value of this function).

Here is the part of concerned HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-loaded" rv-slide="context:stepHide" style="display: block;">
   <!-- rivets: each-contract -->
   <div class="owl-stage-outer">
      <div class="owl-stage" style="transition: 0s; width: 654px; transform: translate3d(218px, 0px, 0px);">
         <div class="owl-item active center" style="width: 109px;">
            <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">243992</div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 109px;">
            <div class="primaryContract selected" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">444444</div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 109px;">
            <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">665441</div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item" style="width: 109px;">
            <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">243992</div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item" style="width: 109px;">
            <div class="primaryContract selected" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">444444</div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item" style="width: 109px;">
            <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">665441</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is my concerned JS:

```
initializeSelectedCarouselItem:function(){
        var items = $("div.primaryContract");
        var index = items.index('.selected');
        console.log(index);
```

Does someone see where made I the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason why it was not working**

You where trying to pass a class `.selected`, while `index()` was expecting an object or DOM element.

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.
>   If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.

**Changes made**

```
var selector = $('.selected')
var index = items.index(selector);
```

**Working Demo**

```js
var items = $("div.primaryContract");
var selector = $('.selected')
var index = items.index(selector);
alert(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-loaded" rv-slide="context:stepHide" style="display: block;">
  <!-- rivets: each-contract -->
  <div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage" style="transition: 0s; width: 654px; transform: translate3d(218px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="owl-item active center" style="width: 109px;">
        <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">243992</div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 109px;">
        <div class="primaryContract selected" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">444444</div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 109px;">
        <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">665441</div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 109px;">
        <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">243992</div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 109px;">
        <div class="primaryContract selected" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">444444</div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 109px;">
        <div class="primaryContract" rv-text="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-value="contract:primaryContractReference" rv-addclass="context:primaryContract | eq contract:primaryContractReference | if 'selected'">665441</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Adil Sorry, I didn't get you Adil. I have already added Demo

Comment: I thought you have Working Demo link but you probably made in page demo here.

Comment: @Adil Please check your console. I'll change it to alert.

Comment: @Adil I have made that to `alert()` for better understanding `:)`

Comment: Your Demo is fine with console.log no need for alert. I first thought Demo is on some external site like jsfiddle.net but later realized you made in-page demo within answer.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `index()` will return the index of child from its parent only and not from grand parents. So, You have use its parent as a child to use grand parent as a parent

```
initializeSelectedCarouselItem:function(){
    var index = $(".primaryContract.selected").parent().index();
    console.log(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get parent index because **primaryContract** is the only child of parent div

Flow this code

```
var index = $(".primaryContract.selected").parent().index();
```

or

```
var indexes=[];
$(".primaryContract.selected").each(function(){
    indexes.push($(this).parent(".owl-item").index());
});
alert(indexes);
```

Comment: Use `.map()` for achieving the second answer instead of looping and pushing.

Comment: `var array = $(".primaryContract.selected").map(function(){
  return $(this).parent(".owl-item").index();
}).get();`